# Qt3D : MultiView with MultiCamera Controller

Tags: qt, qt3d

I am using QML MultiViewport example.

I would like to use `OrbitCameraController` for cam1 and `FirstPersonCameraController` for cam2.
Problem is that wherever I move the mouse, both cameras moves.

How do I do make `OrbitCameraController` move when I move the mouse from viewport1 and `FirstPersonCameraController` from viewport2 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finnally manage camera changes with an QObjectPicker (implementation is cpp, but idea is the same for QML)

```cpp
    auto picker = new Qt3DRender::QObjectPicker(rootNode);
    QObject::connect(picker, &Qt3DRender::QObjectPicker::pressed, [&](Qt3DRender::QPickEvent* pick) {
        if (pick->viewport() == viewport1)
        {
            orbitCameraController->setEnabled(true);
            firstPersonCameraController->setEnabled(false);
        }
        else if (pick->viewport() == viewport2)
        {
            orbitCameraController->setEnabled(false);
            firstPersonCameraController->setEnabled(true);
        }
    });
    rootNode->addComponent(picker);
```